# Java deserializing part of the JSON into object and the rest into JsonObject

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, gson

I was looking everywhere how to deserialize part of the JSON into an object and the rest into JsonObject.

for example:

```
{
  "id" : "123",
  "message" : {"subject" : "test sub" , "body" : "test body"}
}
```

I want to deserialize this JSON into this class:

```
public class className {
    private String id;
    private transient JsonObject message;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The problem is that after the deserialization I get empty object `{}`inside "message".

Does anyone have any idea about it?

======================================================

EDIT:

A little more info, I am using Spring MVC, the JSON is being sent by POST message into my controller.

The controller function looks like this:

```
public @ResponseBody String publish(@RequestBody final className input, final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {
    //input.message = {}
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This works fine for me. Are you sure you're using the right `JsonObject` type from Gson? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am using `com.google.gson.JsonObject`. I am getting the input into my REST controller using POST request with the JSON in the body. the controller looks like this: `public String sendMessage(@RequestBody final className input, ...);` I am stopping with breakpoint right after the entrance to the function and check my input, the ID is there but message is empty

Comment: So Spring MVC and potentially Jackson are involved. Please provide those details in your question.  Is Jackson on the classpath?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because Spring tries to parse your object with Jackson library while your object holds Gson objects (which can't be parsed with Jackson).

Please refer [Configure Gson in Spring](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/023-configure-integrate-gson-spring-boot/).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter < ? >> converters) {
        GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        converters.add(gsonHttpMessageConverter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using Spring Boot so I have added to my appConfig: `@Bean public HttpMessageConverters customConverters()` from the tutorial and on my Application I added `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { JacksonAutoConfiguration.class })` But now "message" is null. not even '{}'.  Do you have any other Idea?

Comment: OK! I got it. the problem with the null was because I had transient keyword on the message field. I have removed the transient and now it works! Thank you very much!